# How to send data from Arduino GIGA to my local server using the HTTP protocol and the POST method?

Tags: http, post, arduino-uno

I've been attempting to send data through Arduino Giga R1 to my local server using the HTTP protocol and the POST method, but I'm encountering some issues.
Let me share one of the codes I've tried. Unfortunately, this specific code doesn't send anything, for instance:

```
    #include <WiFi.h>
   char ssid[] = "netis_70F8D0";       
   char pass[] = "carlos4523";       
   int keyIndex = 0;                
   String data = "serie=777&temp=43";
   int status = WL_IDLE_STATUS;
   char server[] = "http://192.168.166.103/api/dataRealTime";      

   WiFiClient client;

   void setup() {
  //Initialize serial and wait for port to open:
   Serial.begin(9600);
   while (!Serial) {
    ;
   }

   // check for the WiFi module:
   if (WiFi.status() == WL_NO_SHIELD) {
   Serial.println("Communication with WiFi module failed!");
   // don't continue
   while (true);
  }

  // attempt to connect to Wifi network:
  while (status != WL_CONNECTED) {
    Serial.print("Attempting to connect to SSID: ");
    Serial.println(ssid);
    // Connect to WPA/WPA2 network. Change this line if using open or WEP network:
    status = WiFi.begin(ssid, pass);

    // wait 3 seconds for connection:
    delay(3000);
  }
  Serial.println("Connected to wifi");
  printWifiStatus();
**client.connect("http://192.168.166.103", 3001)**


}

   void loop() {

   client.print(String("POST ")+"http://192.168.166.103/api/dataRealTime"+" HTTP/1.0\r\n"
        "Host: "+"192.168.166.103"+"\r\n"+
        "Accept: *"+"/"+"*\r\n"+
        "Content-Length: "+String(data.length())+"\r\n"+
        "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urencoded\r\n"
        "\r\n"+data);
   }
```

I've tried the HttpClient library, similar to how I did it using the ESP32. However, it seems that the HttpClient library I was using doesn't have a default constructor, and there might be differences in the library implementation for the GIGA platform.
Or if someone can provide some guidance or a different way to send data to my local server, it would be very appreciated

Note:
I know my local server works fine because I used it with the ESP32.

Comment: you can use ArduinoHttpClient library. see the examples